# Implement "Connect By Prior" with Lambda Expresseion?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, oracle11g

I Have this query in Oracle and I want to write this with Lambda Expression (LINQ):

```
select b.cod_busun
from pds_business_units b
connect by prior b.busun_cod_busun = b.cod_busun
start with b.cod_busun = 116305033;
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Probably you want not Lambda but LINQ to SQL?

Comment: I want to use this code in my MVC.net program. something like this: var list=db.PdsBusinessUnits.Where(c => c.CodBusun == 116305033)

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is not SQL; the LINQ keywords are defined per-language, and do not include "connect" or "start".

Is "connect" synonymous with "join"? That *is* a LINQ keyword; "start" looks closest to "Skip" (not a keyword, but an extension method). Your specific LINQ implementation *may* (or may not) included methods for writing such queries.